# How to know from which country user has called wcf service?

Tags: wcf

My wcf service is being called from console or window application .How to know from which country user has called the service?

Answer (score 0):

at first you need the consumer IP address. you can get it simply like this:

```
var iPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

then you should extract the IP address information. there are lots of free API in order to do that. i use this one: http://ip-api.com